# Pandas - Data reshaping

Tags: python, pandas

I have an original data table as below:

| id | x1_y1 | x1_y2 | x1_y3 | x2_y1 | x2_y2 | x2_y3 | x3_y1 | x3_y2 | x3_y3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 |
| B | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 |
| C | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.2 |

I would like to convert this table to the following format:

| id | y | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | y1 | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| A | y2 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| A | y3 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| B | y1 | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| B | y2 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| B | y3 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| C | y1 | 0.9 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| C | y2 | 0.3 | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| C | y3 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |

I tried to do manually with Excel using transpose function. But it is only feasible for small dataset. Is there any way to automate these using pandas?